# How can i get the adapter Position of the clicked item in recyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I am trying to pass the selected row value to the next Fragment but onClick on list item I getting error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=-1"

Please help me where I am getting it wrong.

This is my adapter class file for reference, I am not getting where I am getting wrong to solve this issue.

```
 public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        final Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View addressList = inflater.inflate(R.layout.soc_search_list, parent, false);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(addressList);
        try {
            viewHolder.searchList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.clear();

                    Fragment fragment = new UserReg();
                    final int position = viewHolder.getLayoutPosition();

                    address = socAddressList.get(position).getAddress();
                    socName = socAddressList.get(position).getSocName();


                    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),socName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    args.putString("socAddress", address);
                    args.putString("socName", socName);
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragment.setArguments(args);
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment);

                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        return new ViewHolder(addressList);
    }


 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Society_Address society_address = socAddressList.get(position);
        String mtvSocName, mtvLandmark, mtvArea, mtvTown, mtvDistrict, mtvPincode, mtvState, mtvAddress;
        TextView tvSocAddressList;
        mtvAddress = society_address.getAddress();
        tvSocAddressList = holder.socAddress;
        holder.socAddress.setText(socAddressList.get(position).getAddress());
        tvSocAddressList.setText(mtvAddress);


    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView socAddress;
        private LinearLayout searchList;


        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            searchList = itemView.findViewById(R.id.searchlayout);
            socAddress = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_socName);
        }


    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return socAddressList.size();
    }
```

This code populate the list

```
sv_address.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(final String newText) {
                if (newText.length() == 0) {
                   displayList();
                } // This is used as if user erases the characters in the search field.
                else {
                    list = new ArrayList<>();
                    final List<String> docList = new ArrayList<>();
                    CollectionReference mdb = db.collection("AllSocAddress");
                    mdb.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                    list = new ArrayList<>();
                                    List<String> docList = new ArrayList<>();
                                    List<Society_Address> myList = task.getResult().toObjects(Society_Address.class);
                                    myList.clear();
                                    try{
                                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                                docList.add(document.getId());
                                                Society_Address society_address= document.toObject(Society_Address.class);
                                                society_address.address = document.getString("Address");
                                                String socName = document.getString("Society_Name");
                                                text = newText.toUpperCase();
                                                society_address.socName = text.replace(" ","").toUpperCase();
                                                if(socName.contains(text)){
                                                    myList.add(society_address);
                                                }
                                            }
                                            Society_Address_Adapter adapter = new Society_Address_Adapter(getActivity(),myList);
                                            rv_address.setAdapter(adapter);
                                }
                            }
                                    catch (Exception ex){
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),ex.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                }
                    });
                }
                if(adapter!= null){
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: on what instance of adapter do you call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();? In OnCompleteListener you set adapter directly and don't save it somewhere

Answer (score 1):

`viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()` or inside `ViewHolder` just `getAdapterPosition()`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()` and check if it more than 0 or equeal, because it can retutn INVALID_POSITION in curtain circumstances. `viewHolder.getLayoutPosition()` relates to position in layout and sometimes it doesn't correspond to `viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()`.

Comment: Still getting the same error. I tried both getLayoutPosition as well as getAdapterPosition.

Comment: Then it seems something wrong with your code, but it's hard to say exactly without full listing.

Comment: It will help a lot, especially those parts where you access  socAddressList

Comment: How to you get  socAddressList? May be you modify source list somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
```

Comment: even after replacing getLayoutPosition() with getAdapterPosition still getting the same error